# Bullet list text indent/align after tab

Tags: ms-word, alignment, indentation, word-2013

What I'm trying to do is create a bullet list in 'two columns'. So you have the bullet, a word, a tab and some aligned text like in the example below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9gok.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several alternatives:

1. Create a two-column table, with invisible lines. Fill the first column with your "bullet" word, and the second column with your "definition" (or whatever you are putting there.
2. Adjust the formatting for your special list item to include a tab where you want the text to appear and provide a "hanging indent" that lines up overflow text with that tab.

The second option is probably the best for you.